# How to sort a list within an array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a array in Python given by

`matrix = [[10, -9, 8], [1, 15, 5]]`

I want to sort the elements of the matrix[0] list so that matrix[1] is organized according to the ascending order of matrix[0]. The expected result would be:

`matrix = [[-9, 8, 10], [15, 5, 1]]`

My matrix represents values of X and Y. I want to sort X in ascending order so that Y is sorted according to the positions of X, in order to not lose the pairs formed by (X[i], Y[i]).

How can i do that?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Number of rows and columns of matrix will be same or the shape will change?

Comment: Do you want to modify the existing data structure or create a new one? And does the result need to be a list of lists or can it be a list of tuples?

Comment: My matrix represents values of ```X``` and ```Y```. I want to sort ```X``` in ascending order so that Y is sorted according to the positions of ```X```, in order to not lose the pairs formed by ```(X[i], Y[i])```.

Comment: @ProjetosProgramação Are you using or fine to use `numpy`?

Comment: How about: `[list(x) for x in zip(*sorted(zip(matrix[0], matrix[1]), key=lambda y:y[1], reverse=True))]` just for fun. Obviously a bit complex so wouldn't typically do this in a single line of code, but just providing for interest's sake.

Comment: @jarmod This will sort the both rows, right?

Comment: @shaikmoeed correct, as the OP requested afaik (see the OP's expected result). I assume the goal is to retain the entire column.

Comment: Important terminology note, that is a *list* that contains other *lists*

Comment: @jarmod In OP, *matrix[1] is organized according to the ascending order of matrix[0]*, I assume, OP wants to sort the first row and arrange values of the second row based on sorted indices of the first row.

Comment: @shaikmoeed thanks, I think you're right and I need to swap. Let me check and will fix comments shortly.

Comment: Fix above one-liner: `[list(x) for x in zip(*sorted(zip(matrix[0], matrix[1]), key=lambda y:y[0]))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
matrix = [[10, -9, 8], [1, 15, 5]]

matrix[0] = sorted(enumerate(matrix[0]), key=lambda k: k[::-1])
matrix[0], matrix[1] = [v for _, v in matrix[0]], [matrix[1][i] for i, _ in matrix[0]]

print(matrix)
```

Prints:

```
[[-9, 8, 10], [15, 5, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/), it make your job easy, if you have more matrix related operations, check @Andrej Kesely's answer for plain python version

```
matrix = np.array([[10, -9, 8], [1, 15, 5]])
matrix[:, matrix[0, :].argsort()]
```

**Output:**

```
array([[-9,  8, 10],
       [15,  5,  1]])
```